# marionette effect for IOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, character, effect, shake

I'm trying to build an app that has a moveable character as its main idea.

The concept:

Every time you shake your Iphone you will shake several parts of the character (arms, legs, torso, head) by its joints.

I managed to use accelerometer to detect the shake effect, but I'm not able to come to a conclusive approach on how to more the character's body parts.

Ideally, every time you shake the phone the character would move around with a gravity effect like.

Any idea about how I could achieve such effect in xcode?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a physics engine?

check out Box2D:

http://box2d.org

If you want a gravity like effect you could attack the limbs to a torso physics body and then apply the force to the "torso" of the character to get a ragdoll type of effect. You could base the force that you apply on how the device was shaken. I'm not sure if that's what your going for or not though for a shake effect.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I think this can be the right direction to take from here. I will look at the box2d.org documentation and see if the provide some sample codes. Ragdoll was the type of effect I was looking for. I will followup on this later on.